# Ubuntu looses all apps and settings

Tags: 18.04, gnome

I was using my Ubuntu 18.04 to surf the internet. My system froze in the process. I held the power button to turn it off. On restart I got this login screen:

[image: The login screen I got instead of Ubuntu login screen]

And then I all my apps disappear from the app list. The color is different.

System asking to enter login ring:

[image: ring]

New system color:

[image: New system color].

[image: new system color].

[image: more images]

Please how do I fix it?

Comment: Which website did you go on? Some viruses that can be picked up online can do that to your computer.

Comment: Is this your personal computer or a work/school computer? You should never see such a strange login screen. I suspect your computer became infected with something on the web.

Comment: Your display environment has changed. Did you manually change from gdm3 to lightdm, or something else? Did you install any new fonts/themes? At the login screen, select your username, then click on the cogwheel icon, tell me what choices you see, and tell me what is selected.

Comment: @heynnema there's no cogwheel icon to select it's just and input field for the username. After I enter the username, the input field for the password appears.

Comment: @Gordster it's my personal laptop. I'm pretty new to Ubuntu. I've been using it for 2 months now

Comment: @Jeff I was uploading some files via FTP to a hosting server.

Comment: The cogwheel normally appears after the username is selected, and it's near the password field. Check again and get back to me. Otherwise, log in, open `terminal`, and type `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3` and set gdm3 as your DE. Report back.

Comment: @heynnema I did that. I selected gdm3 but I get an error saying gdm.service is not active, cannot reload. invoke-rc.d initscript gdm3, action "reload failed"

Comment: That message is ok, as gdm3 is not currently running, so it can't be reloaded. Just reboot and see if anything has changed for the better.

Comment: @heynnema Still the same situation. I'm currently backing up my files. I'm considering wiping and reinstalling Ubuntu in the morning.

Comment: If you reinstall, uncheck the "format" checkbox, and it should leave your /home folder as is. Good luck. Please keep me posted, ok?

Comment: I don't know what that first login but, on the other screens, it looks like you installed gnome shell. Also, some of the display managers don't have the cog wheel by the username but they do have something you can click at the top bar to select your desktop environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is fixed. Apparently running

> dconf reset -f /

fixed it